# Need to log into Asgardeo through api via POSTMAN

Tags: authentication, postman, wso2-asgardeo

Need to log into Asgardeo through API via POSTMAN. Please share the request and endpoint.

Comment: could you please elaborate more on your requirement? Do you want to authenticate and invoke an Asgardeo API using Postman?

Comment: Actually I have created an user though postman API to Asgardeo. And UI team saying to "you have to authorize the user with userName and password or userId. " what is the Asgardeo endpoint and request that I need to pass from POSTMAN . Please help me on this situation.

Comment: User authentication through API is not yet supported in Asgardeo.

Answer (score 0):

API based user authentication is not yet supported by Asgardeo. Hence, the best case of validating the user for now would be to create a user using the [SCIM API call](https://wso2.com/asgardeo/docs/content/apiDocs/scim2.html#/schemas/BulkUserCreateObject) and the response 201 can be asserted.